# Execution failed for task ':gotroute:processDebugResources'

Tags: android, gradle

**UPDATED**:
Sorry for my broken English
I got this problem for a long time and didn't find a solution.

In this app，I got used **volleyRequest**, **Gson**, **Google Map API**, **WebView**, **Spinner**, **fragment**.

I got this error when I try to build this app into an Android APK. But I can direct run on emulator device.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --output /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/transforms/dex/debug/folders/1000/1f/main /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_c68492cc78a3f92f502a1c62cf56d2ed2bec1f55.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_62638f5857b63749284c794ba7208cd9b4711686.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_327d973a322f3d133cf3a04a0e971c09246fd01e.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_267646e7856b1085ab7e87f018cf02c8fef7261b.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_23999158275a87a0a5358d8af2867134aecdf908.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_ce5d1e02e8da052f64b3a4fe50cecfd6f2cbae5f.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_4a2d11953b453238989bfd9a562abde84465124a.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_aac7a56de62db6cb52e1849a37e105199c48c0df.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_75625afee16f6f36d89511459dac089002d10c14.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_c7f0f7ef45a2ecbee3e9dd706d043e2013273fab.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_c344d0729fee21a480151b65a32c3aa41ddf7d18.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_49f18d5c3e88b19a141db05b34550718c6615d18.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_c817043974012b1b4c775d32c95c818523bb0f11.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_badf31927d318fe0767845ee65b13b2611b571f4.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_bc853713f0e84705308c2146f3ce48d6e050920f.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_4e6e23a77da549cd28e7dde3907c5b88e4e9fa45.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_7ba50c8cd2ea3a4fbfa7ca17cd9d8c79d1685d6a.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_5bde0114ba12ae6e92ca40083d5cfbf92fef1412.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/debug_552111fba4f1fea437fe7095e5bffa05307a303a.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_a5182fb65c07623a04053806bac2b69432c366b1.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_ee173547595db43ddfe7a47119b96f4730dd7b38.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_a5b2e9d8d11329be8435d250a5f309d43c0df8fa.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_892e37526af66b272df338cc782668d252864351.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/mongo-java-driver-3.6.1_4542d9cbc62198a8a529e692c7a29b75726a7831.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_24c584efc3346683786de7beff2ab2df3eb682cb.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_be6affcd9af7c361b6354b3f67a49a26e39e0730.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_ab4c7465b09e5551766dea17cd8a6ae4f193a5d7.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_5bf53582c105251c25ab5527a7f964e6a29f075b.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_3221ad30f3e89f3c935e3fa3726a3714a59cebf9.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_18c2aac6ebb68336c3907fed06f28617dd67f315.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_3ceab68fe71d5dfe50c913d9dece9dd24d281346.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_442a6dc716e224e4a223df8ce871959501417345.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_20a1b5248647d33141cd44bbf499ec39a9a7a182.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_608d37e70495d63b55ea7a81891c37c98d18ebae.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_e2d92c8b4a5361ee630750c491ee7c4e1721f997.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_0091c386bd565b2d688657c107c0d409a4d6ac8f.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_9e32b7b1dcf3d39cad0af5c9d052bd5c79695623.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_c8f3115ab85656f0223873a6170d3fa8cd6a056d.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_10e7f1632c3cc11f8eb93c841d4d9f8d4085e6eb.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_acb4591e5bae90b07b49a63e114ff6f1c3917a7b.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_73e23c802bbe08f4bf437d2efd56cc5a32389640.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_ae0f779bc7a6d62aee2168e5bc70664a022c2ce7.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_94ab729a39d746f336e79be75a43a1329e46ecd6.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_7aced6b867d4d2a775c88aaf7cc133bee154364a.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_80cb7978f7b8fc36cc3478ce623d5414f529eda5.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/common-1.0.3_3b9bcfaec1b8cfa7abf2e36506b0e7456d235ecb.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_7cef16af44529b3a1afb314ac500d9197bcd9d21.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_be9b329bc400e38d515d8ae255b83f526359f545.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_dbedffed4f3d1672f955703de8d513d083d06c25.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/common-1.0.0_2706424f64b67787f323ed493a452236e7d95b58.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_a6a95453b073abee42f240b551fa5b22c1307d90.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_3c4d9e89cf704e2e12250dfaf0a46c64950cbf8d.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_28130fe43c2d7b67a42075ce42d62c39a8d1e595.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_a85578d3fdebf5ec7cae61b4e1135022e7c6518e.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_07942a3e0dafecaf065bfe286e590631777ce988.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_a932668bb72ab88a671de2b4089d557a343e8aba.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_4377e963597053ceaf32e2b0935c0c51ae3001ab.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_eb9ebec90843055017e12a632ba9e8c34c762095.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_3b2cec61d5bd5552a3cec482ffdf95af1c6b7e05.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_e4fcf7b495b61d281e7a5581e9ca9dcb772b44d6.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/gson-2.8.2_054c4917edb12ea5b4192ca1ebdef5b2f53b109b.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_690565a916d0884318f98681f109463c3d61fc28.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_ec7d152c7ec8c3e59ad2aecde635601faa42f7da.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/constraint-layout-solver-1.0.2_23781585e34ce5d6bc51da857f31d2bfb3a1a0ca.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_5dc0f4e0c12d03f02a6ea39d88840c92024707b5.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/support-annotations-27.0.2_7cc92c5df8c05b3c1471cf383a236b36be4ae712.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_dd8a06f793cb38641b4d97dc09c2eeb6ccbf0246.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_1bfc6f72859a902939e4500678f6f9aa5d2a064a.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_c19960b8d9d03206da36efbc833cf7957ebb7941.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_a10162c22fb68741382a54c7d4c2ea765c803ebc.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_540d3c9a235de8df1ab74353a3429d38f9f0a80b.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_c24c70e4865375e11d3041a19f25fb9441c779d3.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_86007efb55f9eca6bac1f4fdfba82b40c648c754.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_c92a3bbb8a9b200a4f01c4bdaaadf49d7d947556.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_38c2f750331a674c1cd4a9d7cd7404483b4875d3.jar /home/gibson/WorkPlace/SoftwareProject/2017_ITSE_HandsomeLee/BaseProject-master/gotroute/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes_618561d0d7659df1a1dc8e8fcfde6b2152d356b5.jar}
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:104)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at 
.............
```

This is my gradle build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.handsomelee.gotroute"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.4'
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile 'com.github.evgenyneu:js-evaluator-for-android:v4.0.0'

}
```

Please give me some method to fix this bug
Thanks

Comment: Tried to make the language clearer

Comment: @Michael sorry for my broken english

Comment: Can you post the full error? It should be a few lines above the stacktrace and should start with "Error:".

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska Sorry for late reply. i cant post the error it say it was too long.

Comment: @IzabelaOrlowska I had Updated the code at the top.

Comment: When do you get this error? When you compile your app? Or when you run it?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice build a apk

Comment: @Gibson Kong This doesn't look like an error you'd get during processDebugResources task, looks like an error with dexing. Can you give full logs?